# In Stock not updated although the quantity has changed

Tags: jquery, sql

I have a form that will create new quotation. Then the new quotation details will be display in the main page. The user can edit that quotation to update or change the quotation details. My problem is when the user change the quantity, it will deduct the actual stock.

1. The current In Stock is 3, while the quantity is 78
[image]

2. The current In Stock is 3 which is still the same as previous one although the quantity has changed to 44
[image]

3. If I add 2nd item, the In Stock of 1st item changed to -41
[image]

4. Inventory stock for certificate cover is 3 which is not updated after add or deduct quantity (picture 2)
[image]

This is my code

```
function InStock() {
          _datatableData.forEach(function (rowData) {
              var ID = rowData.ID;

              var quantity = parseInt($("#txtQuantity" + ID).val(), 10);
              if (!quantity) { quantity = 0; }

              var id = $("#txtItem"+ID).select2("val");
              console.log("stock id :" + id);

             $.ajax({
               url: "../WS/wsQuotation.asmx/GetStockInfo",
               type: 'GET',
               data: {
                   StockID: id ,
               },
               success: function (data) {

                   var json = JSON.parse(data);

                   var instock = parseFloat(json[0]["Inventory_Quantity"]);

                   $("#txtStock" + ID).val(instock - quantity);

               },
              error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText + ":  " + error);
               }
              });
         });

    }
```

SQL query to update stock

```
sqlQuery = @"Update Inventories SET Inventory_Quantity = @Inventory_Quantity WHERE Inventory_ID = @Inventory_ID";
            SqlParam.AddSqlParam("@Inventory_Quantity", quotationDetail[i].ID_Stock, DbType.String);
            SqlParam.AddSqlParam("@Inventory_ID", quotationDetail[i].ID_Item, DbType.String);
            Adapter.ExecuteNonQuery(sqlQuery, SqlParam);
```

Comment: i dont understand fully but tip 78-48+15=45. Also  val(instock - quantity); should be on server side because dual count logic in presentation and backend does hard to find the bugs.

Comment: and @Inventory_Quantity", quotationDetail[i].ID_Stock // i think ID_Stock is not quantity

Comment: @daremachine  (refer picture 3)   ,    3 - 44 = -41